# How to get an aggregated max and min latitude and longitude from a geopoint field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called `location` with `lat` and `lon` properties.

How can I get an aggregated max and min for these fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with a `stats` metrics aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "lat": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "location.lat"
      }
    },
    "lon": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "location.lon"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get the min and max for both the latitude and longitude.

If you don't want to compute unnecessary values, you can also use the `min` and `max` metrics aggregations, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "min_lat": {
      "min": {
        "field": "location.lat"
      }
    },
    "max_lat": {
      "max": {
        "field": "location.lat"
      }
    },
    "min_lon": {
      "min": {
        "field": "location.lon"
      }
    },
    "max_lon": {
      "max": {
        "field": "location.lon"
      }
    }
  }
}
```